# Skip the activities in between and reach the specific activity in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments, android-studio

I have following app structure

- MainFragmentActivity

  - Notification Fragment
  - MainFragment
  - ChatFragment
  - So on etc.

I also have set a broadcast on all "Activities" That will show a popup if any Push notification is arrived.

The popup has two options, View or Ok.

Now let's say i am on ChatFragment , from there i go to Chat Contacts List ( Activity) Then on a ChatScreen(Activity) then on ProfileScreen(Activity) of User

The Stack of Activities will be like

```
MainFragmentActvity -> ChatContactsList -> ChatScreen -> ProfileScreen
```

What i want is, when i click on "View" on ProfileScreen it should remove all stack activities and take back to MainFragmentActivity and replace its Current Fragment with NotificationFragment.

I can do `finishAffinity()` Restart the app and put MainFragment but i want to support 16- APIS to.

`Flag Clear Top` will remove MainActivity and i do not want to restart it because then it has to call a lot of apis

I do not want to put `NO History FLAG` because i need to put All other activities in History.
What can i do here .

Also i do not want to put `startActivityForResult` it would be so complex.
Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: I think in this complex scenario you will have to override the back key event and define custom logic there.

Comment: finish the activty,when ever your starting the StartActivity(intent); finish the current activty

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your explaination is, you want to create wizard like scenario to control the activities flow at run time. (Wizard means, for example, installation window(wizard) of application on microsoft windows)

1. For that, there is already developed library by *Nimrod Dayan*,
   called ***WizarDroid***.

   Here is the link for home page of the same, [WizarDroid](https://nimrodda.github.io/WizarDroid/)

   Try it out, its good.

or

2. You can use ***view pager*** (WizarDroid is also built on view pager)